# htaccess rewrite domain -> to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Have question redirect in htaccess

What I tried to have is

1. my actual domain example https://domain1.com should redirect to new domain2.com/test - but only in case that it is exactly https://domain1.com
2. for all other requests it should redirect to https://domain2.com
   example https://domain1.com/pic001.jpg should redirect to https://domain2.com/pic001.jpg

How can I dow that in `.htaccess`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rewrite check if request is root (/) example https://domain1.com/, second rule  rewrite everything else. Please check it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/test [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: perfect great - Thanks so much - works as it should Regards Carsten